# Buildozer error when compiling Android: list index out of range inside _install_p4a

Tags: android, python, kivy, python-3.6, buildozer

I'm currently trying to compile a  simple Kivy app for use on Android. It runs in both my windows and linux environments without errors or warnings. When I go to package it using buildozer I get an error almost immediately. I did search for this error and although the title is very similar to other questions, the error is not.
Output from buildozer:

```
(mykivyinstall) oli@Bud: buildozer android debug
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Install platform
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/oli/mykivyinstall/bin/buildozer", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/oli/mykivyinstall/lib/python3.6/site-packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/oli/mykivyinstall/lib/python3.6/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 1059, in run_command
    self.target.run_commands(args)
  File "/home/oli/mykivyinstall/lib/python3.6/site-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 92, in run_commands
    func(args)
  File "/home/oli/mykivyinstall/lib/python3.6/site-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 102, in cmd_debug
    self.buildozer.prepare_for_build()
  File "/home/oli/mykivyinstall/lib/python3.6/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 176, in prepare_for_build
    self.target.install_platform()
  File "/home/oli/mykivyinstall/lib/python3.6/site-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 467, in install_platform
    self._install_p4a()
  File "/home/oli/mykivyinstall/lib/python3.6/site-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 524, in _install_p4a
    deps = re.findall("^install_reqs = (\[[^\]]*\])", setup, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

My environment:

```
buildozer version=0.35
cython version=0.25.2
python version=3.6.6
OS is Ubuntu=18.04
```

Am I mixing and matching the wrong versions of things?

Comment: Someone helpfully posted the relevant links https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/pull/724 and https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/731#issuecomment-433614641 , but they got deleted because SO rules discourage useful, correct answers that aren't in the right format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems a like a bug in the latest version of buildozer. The solution is to edit the file "../python3.6/site-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py" and replace the line

```
deps = re.findall("^install_reqs = (\[[^\]]*\])", setup, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)[0]
```

with

```
deps = re.findall("install_reqs = (\[[^\]]*\])", setup, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)[0]
```

Then run `buildozer -v android debug`